# Match only the string that has strings after last underscore

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match string with underscores, throughout the string there are underscores but I want to match the strings that that has strings after the last underscore: Let me provide an example:

```
s = "hello_world"
s1 = "hello_world_foo"
s2 = "hello_world_foo_boo"
```

In my case I **only** want to capture **s1** and **s2**.

I started with following, but can't really figure how I would do the match to capture strings that has strings after `hello_world`'s underscore.

```
rgx = re.compile(ur'(?P<firstpart>\w+)[_]+(?P<secondpart>\w+)$', re.I | re.U)
```

Comment: Some clarification would be nice. Last underscore in `s` is between o and w, in `s1`, it is between d and f and in `s2`, between o and b (but you later say that you want 'strings' after the first underscore, the one between o and w). It seems you have a different meaning of 'string' and 'capture' than the one I have as well. Could you elaborate what you exactly want?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
reobj = re.compile("^(?P<firstpart>[a-z]+)_(?P<secondpart>[a-z]+)_(?P<lastpart>.*?)$", re.IGNORECASE)
result = reobj.findall(subject)
```

**Regex Explanation**

```
^(?P<firstpart>[a-z]+)_(?P<secondpart>[a-z]+)_(?P<lastpart>.*?)$

Options: case insensitive

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “firstpart” «(?P<firstpart>[a-z]+)»
   Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” «[a-z]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “_” literally «_»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “secondpart” «(?P<secondpart>[a-z]+)»
   Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” «[a-z]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “_” literally «_»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “lastpart” «(?P<lastpart>.*?)»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking for (you want to match string with more than one underscore and following text)

```
rgx = re.compile(ur'(?P<firstpart>\w+)[_]+(?P<secondpart>\w+)_[^_]+$', re.I | re.U)
```